# Can't start MySQL 5.6 server after computer is restarted

Tags: mysql

Yesterday I installed MySQL 5.6 and the server was running without any problems..

Is running on Windows 7

But today I can't start the server!?

## error log

```
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [ERROR] InnoDB: read can't be opened in .\ibdata1 mode
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [ERROR] Aborting

2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Binlog end
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2013-04-29 09:59:07 4368 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: can you please append your mysql config and a "ls -la" from your /var/lib/mysql directory?

Comment: He's on Windows

Comment: Uhhm, okay - then I'm out :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL will do this when it can't find the `ibdata1` file in the path specified by the `innodb_data_home_dir` option in `my.ini`.  You should check that path.  Make sure the file is there, and is accessible by the credential in use by MySQL.

If the file is actually gone, as it represents the innodb tablespace, I'm not actually sure the scenario is recoverable except by removing everything and restoring from a backup.

Comment: This it how its configured in the ini `# innodb_data_home_dir=0.0`

Comment: @clarkk when innodb_data_home_dir is undefined (in your config it seems to be), MySQL looks up in the data directory (defined in `datadir` in the config file, defaulting to `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\data` when undefined). You should look for the idbdata1 file and check if your settings in the configuration file really match the on-disk location of your database's files.